# http with different app ports to https with same port

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, port

since hours I try to get an IIS problem solved. I have different application webservers, which will be reached by different ports. subdomain.domain:11701 looks for the webpage created by one app webserver subdomain.domain:11702 looks for another webpage by another app webserver

certs are created ssl is working

http://subdomain.domain.com works

https://subdomain.domain.com works

http://subdomain.domain.com:11701(or 11702, 11703, etc) works

https://subdomain.domain.com:11701 doesn't work (page not found).

IIS pattern test for
`<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^.+$" />`
gives me the right output {C:0} as subdomain.domain.1170n

as I understand should

```
`<action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:0}" appendQueryString="false" />`
```

with {C:0} as the full URL including the port doing the rewriting to https, or do I have here some misconception

Full web.config

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Rewrite to https" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^.+$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:0}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

`

Comment: A single port 11701 can only serve HTTP or HTTPS. You cannot rewrite to the same port with protocol changed.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you very much
probably there isn't a way to change the port during conversion for each entered port as a IIS rule? lets say from http 11701 to 14701 and 1170n to 1470n

Comment: You can use powershell command to check if any process using the port. `Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort YourPortNumberHere).OwningProcess` If the port is free, you can set it such as 1170n to 1470n. You can configure multiple ports per connector/protocol, but you cannot configure multiple protocols/connectors for the same port.